# How to test a Reselect selector from nested reducer?

Tags: redux, expect, create-react-app, reselect

I created a simple Redux selector with the Reselect library. The selector gets the last object in an array.

In the [Reselect docs](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#q-how-do-i-test-a-selector), the testing example is built with Assert library rather than Expect library, but my app originates from React Create App so I have Expect and Jest included.

Anyway, regardless of how I write the selector test, it gets hung up on nested reducer: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'arrayOfObj' of undefined`.

**Selectors.js**

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

const getArrayOfObj = (state) => state.reducer1.arrayOfObj

export const getLastObj = createSelector(
  [ getArrayOfObj ],
  (arrayOfObj) => {
    return arrayOfObj[arrayOfObj.length-1]
  }
)
```

**Selectors.test.js**

```
import * as selectors from 'Selectors'

const mockState = {
    reducer1: {
        arrayOfObj: [
        {id: 1}, 
        {id: 2}, 
        {id: 3}, 
        {id: 4},
      ],
      ...
    },
    reducer2: {
      ...
    }
}

describe('selectors', () => {
  it('getLastObj should get last obj in array', () => {
    expect(selectors.getLastObj(mockState)).toDeepEqual({id: 4});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the error by changing the `expect` statement from `.toDeepEqual()` to `.toEqual()`